# Updating other objects on @PreUpdate with JPA and Play causes exceptions

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I have a Play 1.2.7 project, and need to do the following.
When a particular Article is updated the lastUpdate field is automatically set to the current time. Now related articles need to have their lastUpdate field set to the same as the edited article.

The super class of Article has the following:

```
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    addDate = new Date();
    if(autoLastUpdate) {
        lastUpdate = addDate;
    }
}

@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
    if(autoLastUpdate) {
        lastUpdate = new Date();
    }
}
```

So in the Article class itself I have:

```
@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
    super.onUpdate();
    try{
        this.editedBy = Security.connectedUser();
    } catch (NullPointerException npe){
        this.editedBy = null;
    }

    // Update all lastUpdate on other languages, needed for new selection of articles server side using lastUpdate.
    for (Article article : getAllLanguages()) {
        if (!article.id.equals(this.id) && !article.lastUpdate.equals(this.lastUpdate)) {
            article.refresh();
            article.setLastUpdate(this.lastUpdate);
            article.save();
        }
    }
}
```

But this causes an stack overflow, as when article.save() is called, then actually it seems this.save() is called, as the procedure is run again on the current object:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException has been caught, java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

or a PersistenceException on the Article.save():

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException has been caught, org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: models.Article.accessGroups
```

And I do not understand why. I have spend a few hours on this, as it seems to me simple problem, but cannot figure it out.

Can I not do a save() on another object in the @PreUdate? What way could I otherwise do this automatically on any change on the Article object?

[EDIT:]
An important item which I forgot:

```
public List<Article> getAllLanguages(boolean includeRemoved){
    if(includeRemoved){
        return find("commonId = ? AND commonId != 0 AND site.app = ?", this.commonId, this.site.app).fetch();
    } else {
        return find("commonId = ? AND commonId != 0 AND site.app = ? AND removed = ?", this.commonId, this.site.app, false).fetch();
    }
}
```

I also tried to do the following instead of the above:

```
@PostUpdate
protected void afterUpdate(){
    // Update all lastUpdate on other languages, needed for new selection of articles server side using lastUpdate.
    for (Article anArticle : getAllLanguages()) {
        Logger.debug("Article " + anArticle.id + " time " + anArticle.lastUpdate + " from afterUpdate of " + this.id + " " + this.lastUpdate);
        if (!anArticle.id.equals(this.id) && anArticle.lastUpdate.before(this.lastUpdate)) {
            //anArticle.refresh();
            anArticle.setLastUpdate(this.lastUpdate);
            Logger.debug("Going to save article " + anArticle.id + " from afterUpdate on " + this.id);
            anArticle.save();
        }
    }
}
```

But now I get an error on my test runner, and I do not know what causes it:

```
A java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException has been caught, Index: 1, Size: 0
In /test/models/ArticleTest.java, line 786 :article1.save();

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:962)
    at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:41)
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.save(GenericModel.java:204)
    at models.Article.afterUpdate(Article.java:327)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor571.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.BeanCallback.invoke(BeanCallback.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EntityCallbackHandler.callback(EntityCallbackHandler.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EntityCallbackHandler.postUpdate(EntityCallbackHandler.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.handlePostUpdate(EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.onPostUpdate(EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.postUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:962)
    at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:41)
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.save(GenericModel.java:204)
    at models.ArticleTest.testOnLastUpdatePropagationToOtherLanguages(ArticleTest.java:786)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner$StartPlay$2$1.evaluate(PlayJUnitRunner.java:114)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner.run(PlayJUnitRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at play.test.TestEngine.run(TestEngine.java:112)
    at controllers.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:557)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:508)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:251)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:278)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.run(PlayHandler.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745
```